# Deleting a particular column/row from a CSV file using python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I want to delete a particular row from a given user input that matches with a column.
Let's say I get an employee ID and delete all it's corresponding values in the row. 
Not sure how to approach this problem and other sources suggest using a temporary csv file to copy all values and re-iterate.

Comment: It is possible that you could save the csv as a dataframe with the pandas read_csv, search for the employee id, save that to a variable, then write the new variable to a new csv file. Are you familiar with input/ouput python functions?

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much the way to do it.

Something like:

```
import shutil

file_path = "test.csv"

# Creates a test file
data = ["Employee ID,Data1,Data2",
        "111,Something,Something",
        "222,Something,Something",
        "333,Something,Something"]

with open(file_path, 'w') as write_file:
    for item in data:
        write_file.write(item + "\n")
# /Creates a test file

input("Look at the test.csv file if you like, close it, then press enter.")

employee_ID = "222"
with open(file_path) as read_file:
    with open("temp_file.csv", 'w') as temp_file:
        for line in read_file:
            if employee_ID in line:
                next(read_file)
            temp_file.write(line)

shutil.move("temp_file.csv", file_path)
```

If you have other data that may match the employee ID, then you'll have to parse the line and check the employee ID column specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Since these are very primitive requirements, I would just do it manually.
Read it line by line - if you want to delete the current line, just don't write it back.

If you want to delete a column, for each line, parse it as csv (using the module `csv` - do not use `.split(',')!`) and discard the correct column.

The upside of these solutions is that it's very light on the memory and as fast as it can be runtime-wise.